# position a div over each thumbnail?

Tags: html, css

I have a number of thumbnails, and I want to use CSS to make a div appear over the lower right of each one, to show more information about the image. How do I do that? Not looking for javascript for this static behavior.

I basically have a grid of content (thumbnails), and I want each cell in that grid associated with a second cell, that floats on top of it.

For that class of informational div, I tried using "position: absolute", but you can't specify a position relative to the thumbnail, only the block container above it. I can't make my thumbnails all "display: block", because that forces a new line for every thumbnail and they can't flow together. I can't put my thumbnails into a table, because tds are not "display: block", so "position: absolute" can only be relative to the table, not each cell. Making tds "display: block" forces a new line for every td. Making a container "display: block" and "float: left" also makes "position: absolute" ignore them too.

Am I going to have to put an attribute like style="left: 129px; top: 536px;" in every one of these divs?

Comment: can you please show us some html/css ? example ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this

https://jsfiddle.net/fpygeokn/

```css
.image-wrapper {
  height: 250px;
  width: 300px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}
.image-wrapper img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.image-describe {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 30px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <img src="http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png" />
  <div class="image-describe">
    This is a desciption
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ...yeah. If only I had seen your answer while I was writing the answer to my own question.

Comment: Most important aspect you need to look at is the parent to have a `relative` position and the child text wrapper to have an `absolute` position

Answer (score 1):

Oh, duh. I'm sorry, I forgot that this is exactly what "display: inline-block" is for. My CSS ended up like this:

```
.thumb {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.thumb img {
    width: 11.25vw;
}

.thumb span.taghi {
    position: absolute;
    left: 9vw;
    top: 9vw;
    width: 1vw;
    background-color: rgba(200,100,255,0.3);
    display: inline;
}
```

And the rough HTML would be:

```
<div id="thumbs">
  <div class="thumb">
    <span class="taghi" title="someinfo">(?)</span>
    <a href=...><img src=.../></div>
  <div class="thumb">etc...
```

When you use "display: inline-block" it gets treated as a block element for any "position: absolute" elements inside it, while being flowed like an inline element.